# How can I unescape html tags in lodash.template()?

Tags: javascript, html, lodash

I'd like to create a html code using [lodash.template()](http://lodash.com/docs#template), but the result was not I expected.

```
var a = '<td>a</td>';
var expected = '<tr><td>a</td></tr>';
var actual = _.template('<tr><%- a %></tr>', {a: a});

console.log(actual);
"<tr>&lt;td&gt;a&lt;/td&gt;</tr>"
```

Populated text `a` has been escaped as a result.

How can I get the result as `expected`?

I can set `options.escape`, but have no idea how to use this option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `<%= a %>` or `print` in evaluate context as documented, though generating HTML this way is not recommended for security.

```
var actual = _.template('<tr><% print(a) %></tr>', {a: a});
// or
var actual = _.template('<tr><%= a %></tr>', {a: a});
```